# How do you invert an animation on a shape in Python?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently working on making a game in my grade 10 Computer Science class, and my game is to (so far) have the player move a car up and down with the arrow keys while avoiding different shapes (right now the only shape is one square at the moment for testing), and if it touches the top or bottom of the screen the game is over and the code automatically repeats. I see that the square moves from left to right, but is there a way to make it move from right to left? Here's my code so far.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init() 

gameExit=False

display_width=800
display_height=600
car_height=188

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red=(255,0,0)
blue=(0,0,255)

crashed = False
carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, colour):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, colour, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/8))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()

def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')

def game_loop():
    x =  (display_width * 0)
    y = (display_height * 0.68)

    gameExit=False

    y_change=0

    thing_starty=random.randrange(0, display_height)
    thing_startx=-300
    thing_speed=7
    thing_width=100
    thing_height=100

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)       
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            #Key bindings
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 10
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0        

        y +=y_change    

        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        # things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, colour)
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, blue)
        thing_startx += thing_speed

        car(x,y)    

        if y > display_height - car_height or y < 0:
            crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change`thing_startx=-300` to `thing_startx = display_width` and `thing_speed = 7` to `thing_speed = -7`.